# Can I use the Android Debug Bridge (ADB) and Logcat to see what components of Android OS are accessed by an App?

Tags: android, adb, logcat

Here is the use case -

- I want to plug in an android phone to a Windows machine with Android Studio (`Logcat` running).
- I then want to open an app on the phone, perform a bunch of actions, and then review the log to see if the app accessed location/personal data directory/contacts/etc.

Is there a way to do this without rooting the device?

Does Logcat have a record of such events, or perhaps a logging application I have missed in my searches?

I guess the heart of the question - how do you audit an app to make sure it isn't doing something it should not?

Comment: No you can't. As for making sure an app doesn't do something it "should not," that is what permissions are for. I'll be the first to admit that pre-Marshmallow, the all-or-nothing approach was pretty poor, but that's somewhat better now.

Comment: So if an app does not have permission to access contacts/personal data/location/etc, there's no way it can get around this barrier?  Wireshark/Fiddler would be a better way to look at any data/traffic flow?  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Correct, if an app does not have permission, it can't access that data. For examining traffic, wireshark is probably a good option.